# Euler-Lagrange equation clarification

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, tensors

Consider the metric for a sphere $$ds^2=d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\,{d\phi^2}$$
. The Lagrangian L for the metric $ds^2$ is $$L=\theta'^2+\sin^2{\theta}\,\phi'^2$$, where the ' denotes a derivative with respect to $\tau$. Thus for the systems of Euler-Lagrange equations would be $$\frac{d}{d\tau}(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta'})=2\theta''$$ $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}=2\phi'^2\sin{\theta}\cos\theta$$ $$\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi'}\right)=2\phi''\sin^2\theta+4\theta'\phi'\sin\theta \cos\theta$$ $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}=0$$. So the resulting set of differential equations following the Euler equation we get $$2\phi'^2\sin{\theta}\cos\theta-2\theta''=0$$ and $$0-2\phi''\sin^2\theta+4\theta'{\phi'}\sin\theta \cos\theta=0$$. If this is a set of ordinary differential equations, one with respect to $\theta$ and one for $\phi$. What I dont understand is that there are the derivatives with respect to two different variables in the same equation. These are supposed to be ODEs, would this make them PDEs. how would I solve  the equations? Would I hold one of the other variable derivatives constant? Would I solve as a normal set of ordinary differential equations?

Comment: A couple of typesetting suggestions:  (1) `$$ [math] .$$`, not `$$ [math] $$.` (put the period, comma, whatever *inside* the displayed mathematics, (2) functions like the sine and cosine should be typeset with upright text, e.g. `\sin` rather than `sin` (this will also correct the spacing), and (3) parentheses around fractions should probably be enlarged, e.g. `\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi' \right)`.

Comment: Just to clarify that PDE is used when the unknown function depends on two (or more) variables. For example, $f(x,y) = xy$ satisfies the PDE $x \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} - y\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}= 0$. In your case, both functions depend on the same variable ($\tau$)

Comment: Thank you. I figured that both variables depend on $\tau$. My question is how would I go about solving those equations. I have only dealt with ODEs that only contain 1 derivative like $y'+y''=0$ not $o'+q'=0$. Is there difference?

Comment: Why not arc length primed as independent variable for $(\theta, \phi)?$

Comment: You introduced a sign error in the equation for $ϕ''$.

Answer (score 1):

What makes a differential equation an ODE is that we deal with a function $f:I\to E$, where $I\subset \Bbb{R}$ is some open interval and $E$ is some Banach space (in your case $\Bbb{R}^2$, since we're dealing with two functions $f(t)=(\phi(t),\theta(t))$). I.e the domain is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ "function of one variable", but we can deal with several functions (hence we allow for a vector space as a target space; in this case it happens to be a two-dimensional space, but clearly we can conceive of situations where we need a larger space, and sometimes possible even an infinite-dimensional space).

PDEs are when we have functions $f:U\subset \Bbb{R}^n\to E$, where $U$ is (for example) open in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and typically we reserve the term "partial" for when $n\geq 2$. It's not "wrong" to use the term partial differential equation when $n=1$, but it's just confusing.

So, just to be explicit, the situation we have here is that we consider a function $F:\Bbb{R}^6\to\Bbb{R}^2$
\begin{align}
F((\theta,\phi), (\theta_1,\phi_1), (\theta_2,\phi_2))&:=
\begin{pmatrix}
2\phi_1^2\sin \theta\cos \theta-2\theta_2\\
-2\phi_2\sin^2\theta+4\theta_1\phi_1\sin\theta\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Solving your ODE means we wish to find a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$, $t\mapsto f(t)=(f_1(t),f_2(t))$, such that for all $t\in\Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
F(f(t),f'(t),f''(t))&=F\left((f_1(t),f_2(t)), (f_1'(t),f_2'(t)), (f_1''(t),f_2''(t))\right)=0.
\end{align}

---

So far I have been super formal just to highlight the structural difference between an ODE and a PDE. Of course, rather than calling the functions $f_1$ and $f_2$, the traditional notation is $\theta(\cdot),\phi(\cdot)$.

As for solving the ODEs, I hope you intuitively believe that the solutions should be great circles. Now, the following is definitely not the most efficient way of obtaining this fact, but since you asked for it, here's how I'd do it. Now, I'll go back to the traditional notation.

First of all, note that the Lagrangian doesn't depend on $\phi$, so you already have a conserved quantity; namely $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}}=0$, which means $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\phi}}=(\sin^2\theta) \dot{\phi}=C$ is constant along the solutions of the ODE (i.e this angular momentum is conserved along the geodesic).

To solve fully an ODE, we have to specify initial conditions. This means, I have to specify the initial point $p\in S^2$ and I also have to specify the initial velocity $v_{p,0}\in T_pS^2$. To make life simple, I can rotate my coordinate system appropriately, and work in the domain where $0<\theta<\pi$ and $-\pi<\phi<\pi$ (this is just one possibility for where polar coordinates are well-defined). Now, if I did this rotation "correctly", I can ensure that
\begin{align}
\theta(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}, \quad \phi(0)=0\quad \dot{\theta}(0)=\alpha_0\quad \dot{\phi}(0)=0,
\end{align}
where $\alpha_0\in \Bbb{R}$. In words, by a clever choice of rotation, I can ensure that 2 out of my 4 initial conditions vanish. This is helpful because if I look back at my angular-momentum conservation law, it tells me that for every $t$,
\begin{align}
\sin^2\theta(t)\,\dot{\phi}(t)&=\sin^2\theta(0)\dot{\phi}(0)=0
\end{align}
Since I said $0<\theta<\pi$, it follows that $\sin^2\theta(t)\neq 0$, so I can divide by it to deduce that $\dot{\phi}(t)=0$ for all $t$. Plugging this into the first ODE, I just have to solve $\ddot{\theta}=0$ with $\theta(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\dot{\theta}(0)=\alpha_0$. Hence, the solution is
\begin{align}
\theta(t)=\alpha_0t+\frac{\pi}{2} \qquad \phi(t)=\phi(0)=0
\end{align}

Note that this is just the coordinate representation. The actual curve $\gamma$ in $S^2\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ is given by
\begin{align}
\gamma(t)&=R\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta(t)\cos\phi(t)\\
\sin\theta(t)\sin\phi(t)\\
\cos\theta(t)
\end{pmatrix}\\\\
&=R\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin\left(\alpha_0t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
0\\
\cos\left(\alpha_0t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix},\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
for some rotation matrix $R\in SO(3)$ (if $\alpha_0=0$, it means we're just stuck at a single point, so it's a "degenerate geodesic").

One final technical remark: throughout, we solved this system ODEs in one coordinate chart, so the solutions (as obtained in this coordinate chart) is only defined for a certain small amount of time. However, in our case, we can easily see that this same function, defined for all time, still satisfies the geodesic equation. So, $(*)$ is indeed the solution to the geodesic initial value problem. From that same formula, we can read off that $\gamma$ is a parametrization of a great circle on the sphere. The parameter here is an affinely related to arclength, just as we expect.

Comment: and if you don't like all of this careful coordinate choices I made to simplify the resulting ODE, take a look at [The Geodesic Problem on a Sphere](https://youtu.be/1cZC3iMpDxQ); in this Khan academy video, everything is done "the straight-forward but tedious way"

Comment: Thank you for the clerification on this exercise. So the idea of this is that part of the equation will just go to zero due to various conservation laws, correct?

Comment: yes, one conservation law, and a lot of symmetry